# How to add two variables without making it concatenated in javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
a = document.CPU.Bfirst.value;

w = document.CPU.Afirst.value;

aa = a + w;

k = aa.sub();

document.write(k);
```

*I want the sum of the two values in a subscripted form but it only provides a concatenated value instead of the actual sum.

*Other variables:

```
    a = document.CPU.Bfirst.value;

    b = document.CPU.Bsecond.value;

    c = document.CPU.Bthird.value;

    d = document.CPU.Bfourth.value;

    w = document.CPU.Afirst.value;

    x = document.CPU.Asecond.value;

    y = document.CPU.Athird.value;

    z = document.CPU.Afourth.value;

    e = a - w;

    f = b - x;

    g = c - y;

    h = d - z;

    i = (e + f + g + h)/4;

    aa = a + w;

    bb = aa + x;

    cc = bb + y;

    dd = cc + z;

    j = w.sub();

    k = aa.sub();

    l = bb.sub();

    m = cc.sub();

    n = dd.sub();
```

*Form part:

```
    Enter all needed information:

    



Process

Arrival Time

Burst Time        





A

      







B

      







C

       







D
```

Comment: Please help me. i'm stucked at the addition part.

Answer (score 2):

If your values really are numbers, you can force the conversion with the unary `+` operator:

```
aa = +a + +w;
```

The `value` property of an `<input>` node will always give you a string, and the JavaScript `+` operator really likes strings.

Comment: I've tried this code but it seems that it doesn't work for me. :(

Comment: @sfaw you'll have to post more code then, because this will definitely work if the values really are strings that "look like" numbers.

Comment: Can I have your email? I'll send my codes to you so you can help me more.

Comment: @sfaw no, you should post your stuff here.

Answer (score 2):

If `a` and `w` are INT, you can use `parseInt()`

```
aa = parseInt(a) + parseInt(w)
```

If vars are float use `parseFloat()` instead.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ujumvs99/)

Comment: I also tried this but it doesn't work for me either. :(

Comment: I added a fiddle and it seems to work..

Comment: Have you tried it using my codes?

Comment: Does it need any software requirements? Coz I think parseInt() doesn't work for me.

Comment: I think this works when you put a fixed value of your variables. But in my case, you have to put a random value so I think this makes the parseInt() doesn't work.

Comment: What do you mean with 'fixed value'? However for parseInt() you can refer to http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp